# Behavior of Table.get(List<Get> gets)

Tags: hbase

I would ask when HBase performs batches get with given gets list using `Table.get(List<Get> gets)` , will it use rowkey as index for each get? That is, it would be kind of as fast as single Get.

I ask so, because I have Scan and Filter in mind, Scan with filters,but without startKey/endKey will scan the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

`Scan` without `startRow`/`endRow` will indeed scan the whole table, even with filters. If you know at least the `startRow`, then you can avoid scanning the rest of the table, for example by setting the numeric row limit (so it will know exactly where to start and how many rows max to process). But if you don't know the `startRow` then it's bad. Importantly, keep in mind here that you don't need the WHOLE `startRow` key. You can do partial. For example if your row keys are GUIDs, if you set your startRow as 'FF' it will skip everything up to it and start with 'FF001...' or whatever.

Generally scans are better for getting a sequence of rows. `Get<list>` seems more for a collection of unrelated/non consecutive rows.

*** UPDATE: Oops...

https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/branch-2.0/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.java

```
  default Result[] get(List<Get> gets) throws IOException {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Add an implementation!");
  }
```

I haven't used it before, but that's what it looks like as of 2.0.

If you really need to get a collection of non-consecutive rows at once, in this case I'd suggest looking at the `MultiRowRangeFilter` with a `Scan`. It's a bit of a pain to write it out, but I recall it worked well when I tried using it.

Comment: Thanks, For Get<list>, will each get in the list perform as fast as Table.get(), I just want to confirm how Get(list) works.

Comment: Hah, you made me look at the code. Will try this later myself, but see the updated answer)